# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException with Redemption on web server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outlook-redemption

I'm using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) in an ASP.NET MVC site to read in a .msg file, make some changes and output it to the user. It works on my dev machine but when I try on the staging server, I get this error.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.     at Redemption.RedemptionLoader.IClassFactory.CreateInstance(Object pUnkOuter, Guid& refiid, Object& ppunk)
```

Is it because I don't have outlook installed on the server? My understanding was that Outlook isn't required. I also tried registering the DLLs with regsvr32.exe but that didn't help.

UPDATE: I installed the standalone MAPI suggested by Dmitry and rebuilt my web app to target x64 platform. The server is Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 so I assume 64 bit is the correct target. But it is still giving me the same error. My code looks like this:

```
RedemptionLoader.DllLocation64Bit = Server.MapPath("~/bin/dlls/Redemption64.dll");
RedemptionLoader.DllLocation32Bit = Server.MapPath("~/bin/dlls/Redemption.dll");
Interop.Redemption.RDOSession session = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
```

The third line is throwing the error. Am I missing something?

I also tried compiling the site to target x86 but IIS won't load the site .dll at that point.

Comment: Edit your app pool's advanced settings, 'enable 32-bit applications'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redemption requires the MAPI system to be installed, which means either Outlook or the [standalone version of MAPI](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e17e7f31-079a-43a9-bff2-0a110307611e&DisplayLang=en) must be installed.
Also make sure the bitness of your code matches the bitness of the MAPI system - see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject

Comment: Dmitry, thank you for your reply. But I'm still getting the error. Please see my update above.

Comment: The standalone version of MAPI only comes in 32 bit, so your code must be build as x86.